# case-insensitive поиск в строке, Perl

Tags: perl

В файле есть строка `GCAGcBACGCBgC`, я хочу посчитать количество GC без учета регистра.

```
$count = 0;
$count++ while ($string =~ /GC/gi);
```

Ожидаю в принт получить 4, получаю 2. Что я делаю не так? Ответивший ниже прав, все работает, у меня видимо ошибка в чем-то другом. Вот та часть, где она возникает:

```
local $/;     
open(FILE, "abcd.txt") or die "Can't read file 'filename' [$!]\n";  
$document = <FILE>; 

$document =~ tr/contig/#/;   

$count1 = 0;
$count1++ while ($document =~ />/g);
print $count1 ;  

$count2 = 0;
$count2++ while ($document =~ m/[a-zA-Z]/g);

$count3 = 0;
$count3++ while ($document =~ /GC/gi);
print $count3;
```

Сделал файл, чтобы посмотреть как работает.

```
>contig_239
AAaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbAAAbbbbbbbbbbbbb
sdsdsdsddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddsdsd
sdsdsdsdsdsdsssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssds
FGFGFHSKDJSKDJSKDJSKJDasdaldkalsdkalsdkalsdksaldka
>contig_240
GCAGcBACGCBgC
SDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDSSDSDSDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
SDSDSDSDSDSDSDSDSDSDS
```

Нужно в `$count3` получить 4, потому что "GC" встречается 4 раза в строке `GCAGcBACGCBgC` и только в этой строке, которя идет после contig_240. Запуская в принт получаю два.

Comment: У меня работает как ожидается. Что за версия?

Comment: А какая ошибка? Что в файле? Из файла у меня тоже 4 находит. Вы можете воизпроводимый пример дать?

Comment: Почему вы 4 ожидаете? `tr///` все cg заменит, останется толка 2-а GC.

Comment: Есть файл с последовательности нуклеотидов( по одной букве). Часть последовательности замаскирована, т.е. в файле она нижним регистром. Каждая новая последовательность начинается с >cotig_номер. Мне нужно посчитать сколько последовательностей есть, сколько замаскировано от общего числа нуклеотидов, сколько встречается GC и сколько есть последовательностей, где нижним регистром более 50%. Так как я использую потом lower/uppercase для поиска,  решил заменить все contig на символы, чтобы они не мешали, надеясь что заменится только все слово целиком, а не c,o,n,. Возможно как-то так сделать?

Comment: Я сейчас уже подумал, может я и GC тоже неверно ищу. Мне нужны только GC, gC, Gc, но не CG, Cg, cG

Comment: Дав полное описание задачи,  которую вы решаете, вы не ответили на вопросы, стоящие выше. Что в приведённом коде  не работает?

Comment: Добавил. Вы правы, я убрал tr//, получил что нужно. Есть ли возможность заменить не каждую букву, а только слово целиком?

Comment: Да, есть `s/contig/#/` даст `>#_239` в первой строке.